# Flutter: display TextField text on a different widget

Tags: flutter

How can I do this on same page have 2 different widgets? I want to display the content while I'm typing.

It only works if I assign it to a different variable but could I use the controller.text and avoid creating unnecessary variables and applying the SetState?

```
Widget _price() {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
      title: TextFormField(
        controller: _priceController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: translate('rent.buy_price')),
        maxLength: 5,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty || value == ' ' || value == '') {
            return translate('fill_field');
          }
          return null;
        },
        onChanged: (String newPrice) {
          print(_priceController.text); // I get the correct value
          // also tried SetState() here but doesn't work
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if there is supposed to be an image or code, but it isn't linked in your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a relevant code, so others could help you faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TextEditingController`'s `onChanged` function to call `setState(() {})` to set the text of the other widget in real-time.

```
class Thing extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThingState createState() => _ThingState();
}

class _ThingState extends State<Thing> {
  TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: controller,
          onChanged: (text) => setState(() {}),
        ),
        Text(controller.text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but why I'd have to create a setState for this if I'm already changing the value?

Comment: In order for the changes to be displayed your widget needs to be rebuilt, so you need to call setState. Your sample above is a method with a return type of widget rather than a Stateless or Stateful widget but if it's contained within a Stateful widget you can still call setState to see the changes. My answer shows you how to accomplish that.

Comment: so basically with all form elements (textfields, checkboses, dropdowns...) we need to apply the setstate on the onchange event?

Comment: Basically if you want to update the UI, you need to rebuild the widget. In a Stateful widget, the widget's build method is inside the State class of the widget: 
`class _ThingState extends State<Thing>` so in order to hit `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)` you need to "set the state" again which will hit that build method and rebuild your widget with your Stateful UI changes.